# Does .gltf import in Blender supports importing lights and cameras

Tags: rendering, import, gltf

I've tried importing a .gltf file that I added cameras and lights to. The latter is through the KHR_lights_punctual extension. However, it seems like only the geometry is imported and I don't see any new cameras and lights in the scene collection at the top right.

The goal is to import the scene created elsewhere and render it with Cycles or Eeevee in Blender.
So two questions:

1. Does Blender support importing lights and cameras from .gltf?
2. Is there's another way to import cameras and lights into the Blender scene?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I've set up my .gltf file wrong. If anyone else stumbles over this try exporting a camera and a light from Blender and then mimic the generated content manually.